# Pure Python implementation of OpenSSL to sign files using key

Tags: library, python, ssl

I'm trying to achive something like the command below using python:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign "myky.key" -out outfile.txt.sha256 myfile
```

Actually, I can simulate this behaviour programmatically using [PyCrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) or [PyCryptodome](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycryptodome), but both libraries use Python and C.

I want for a pure Python implementation, since I'll use it in th Google App Engine Environment, and just pure python things works really weel in GAE.

So, do we have any python library for this purpose?

For completeness (and understanding of what I'm doing):

My task is get a file from Google Cloud Storage (Bucket), sign it with a key locally generated and then upload the signed file to Storage again. All these things happening when call a GAE API Endpoint.
All those things are fine, except for the the part of signing the file and that's why I need a Pure Python OpenSSL implementation.

Comment: [This might help.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/ssl_support)